# Is it correct to apply the vis-viva equation to an airplane that flies in a straight line at the Kármán line?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, aerodynamics, lift, karman-line

The [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) models the motion of an **orbiting** body and it applies  when the **only** force acting on the body is it's own weight.

So is it correct to apply this equation to an airplane that flies in a **straight line** at the [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Definition)?

If it's correct, please explain why and if it's not, why not?

I ask this question because I'm puzzled by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29721/what-would-a-k%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n-plane-look-like-a-bird-or-a-plane) from @uhoh about the Kármán plane where the orbital velocity is used to determine the look of the Kármán plane.

v = 4 km/sec --> wing loading = 0,635

v = 3 km/sec -->   ,,  ,,     = 0,31

v = 5 km/sec -->   ,,  ,,     = 1,24

v = 6 km/sec -->   ,,  ,,     = 2,53

v = 7 km/sec -->   ,,  ,,     = 6,97

Comment: @uhoh  Isn't the airplane in the question an example ?

Comment: @uhoh  i've added a link to your question about the Kármán plane

Answer (score 2):

In the example given in the question ([my question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29721/12102)) I use the *vis-viva* equation to calculate the magnitude of orbital velocity. That's what the equation does, and "orbital velocity" is the *term specified and used in definitions* of the Karman line. So without reinventing the Karman line, one can use the vis-viva equation to address the Karman line as it is currently known.

As I say there in the first sentence:

> ...the Kármán line is roughly the altitude where a "Kármán plane's" upward lift force **at the orbital velocity for that altitude** would be equal in magnitude to the gravitational downward force.

To get that velocity at that altitude, you can correctly use the vis-viva equation.

There's nothing about this scenario that says that the object is actually in orbit. It only calls for the velocity that *an object that happened to be in orbit at that altitude* would have.

**The problem may be that this is a definition, not reality. Definitions can be as hypothetical and unrealistic as they want to be.**

Peruse Johnathan McDowell's paper discussed in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32848/12102) for a more thorough mathematical discussion of an "improved definition" of a Karman-like line, which uses the vis-viva equation quite nicely, even though drag and lift are invoked within the definition as well.

Comment: Clear answer, it revealed to me the difference between definition and reality. But that definition on Wiki, where does it come from, on who's authoroty ?

Comment: Someone asked him to come up with a definition, so he did it. Nobody needs authority to come up with a definition. Authority is only needed to *enforce* it somehow. For example, anyone can define what "impaired" by alcohol could mean (for example ability to walk in a straight line without flying), but in some countries a blood alcohol level of 0.08% is *enforced* by a very powerful authority.

Comment: Is there any written evidence that Von Kármán did *not* use the centrifugal force for his calculations ? Because in his comments he compares aerodynamic lift with centrifugal force, i think it's very likely he did !

Comment: @Conelisinspace That's a whole different discussion on one or more other questions already.

Comment: I think everybody that comes up with a definition on Wikipedia needs some authority, according to Wiktionary: "a person accepted as a source of reliable information on a subject ".

Comment: @Conelisinspace Wikipedia is notoriously lacking authority. Literally anyone can add info, edit, make changes...