# Is it correct to use the vis-viva equation when there are two forces acting on the orbiting body?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, aerodynamics, lift, karman-line

> Edit: Although this question seems similar to the question ["Is it correct to apply the vis-viva equation to an airplane that flies in a straight line"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32935/is-it-correct-to-apply-the-vis-viva-equation-to-an-airplane-that-flies-in-a-stra), it is different because *there* the airplane flies in a straight line and in *this question* it is in orbit.

The [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) models the motion of an **orbiting** body and it applies when the **only** force acting on the body is it's own weight.

So is it correct to use this equation to an airplane that flies at the [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Definition) with an orbital velocity that generates a strong [lift force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(force)) ?

I ask this question because i'm puzzled by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29721/what-would-a-k%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n-plane-look-like-a-bird-or-a-plane) from @uhoh about the Kármán plane where the vis-viva equation is used for an airplane.

Comment: Without a specific example this question is too vague to have an answer. "Apply" and "correct" are open to way too much interpretation for this question to have a conclusive answer. If you want to know if X is correct, you have to show X.

Comment: @uhoh i've added a link to your question about the Kármán plane.

Comment: You did that in your [last question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32935/12102), and that was answered there. I still don't think "applied" is unambiguous. Different people can imagine *applying* an equation to have different meanings and functions. This is math and physics equations, and that kind of question should be clear and unambiguous. To me this looks like you are playing games with words, or trying to use a question to make a point, rather than to ask a genuine question.

Comment: @uhoh  So i changed to "use" instead of " apply" .

Comment: Use *to do what exactly?* You are asking for an answer of "correct" or "incorrect" as a wild-card, that you could then apply to *any other use*. I think you should point to a specific use, in such a way that all readers can see which use you mean, and ask if that particular use is correct.

Comment: @uhoh  The vis-viva equation in your question then, what did you do with it ? Did you apply it, or did you use it, or did you just show it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it correct to apply the vis-viva equation to an airplane that flies in a straight line at the Kármán line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32935/is-it-correct-to-apply-the-vis-viva-equation-to-an-airplane-that-flies-in-a-stra)

Comment: @JCRM  Just edited my question to clarify that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see any distinction. and if not a duplicate of that one, it's a duplicate of the many other questions you have asked about @uhoh's question

Comment: @JCRM  Are you really asserting that you don't see the distinction between an airplane that travels horizontal and a plane that is in orbit ?

Comment: @JCRM  Show me the many other questions that would be a duplicate of this one and i will clarify that they are not.

Comment: a velocity is a straight line

Comment: I'm sure the moderators would be amused at that suggestion, Conelisinspace. The fact remains, velocities are straight lines; that the karman plane would continue to fly in a straight line *only* applies at the karman line, after which it no longer apples.

Comment: Given a plane flying in a straight line at the Karman line is, by the definition of the Karman line, flying a circular orbit -- yes I assert there is no difference

Comment: @JCRM  Yes, you're right, i got myself entangled twice by the word "orbital"

Answer (score 2):

[Per definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) the maximal lift generatable at the Kármán line is

$$L = m \cdot g$$

so if your body is generating significant lift at sea level it will probably still generate enough lift at that altitude to divert from a "vis-viva orbit" after a short while. The bigger problem however is drag. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Alternatives_to_the_definition):

> Due to atmospheric drag, the lowest altitude at which an object in a circular orbit can complete at least one full revolution without propulsion is approximately 150 km (93 mi), whereas an object can maintain an elliptical orbit with perigee as low as about 130 km (81 mi) without propulsion.

So simplifying the orbit to have no other forces, as the vis-viva equation states, specifically to be a frictionless one would be a gross misstatement.

In general during deorbit of a spacecraft the altitude around the Kármán line is considered part of the reentry.

[image: friction]

(Image Credit: [Comparison of lifting reentry and ballistic reentry](http://www.tjprc.org/publishpapers/2-67-1524714741-12.IJMPERDJUN201812.pdf) by A. Rathan Babu, P. Vijay Kumar, B. Praveen, and R. Suresh Kumar)

As you can see in the graphic:

1. There is a measurable deceleration for a reentering spacecraft at that altitude
2. The friction depends on the shape, size and orientation of the object

Spy satellites or earth observation satellites orbiting at similarly low altitude usually have a propulsion system firing permanently or quite frequently to keep the orbit and are built to be very aerodynamic to minimize friction.

## TL;DR

There is enough friction at that altitude to make the vis-viva equation not applicable for even short term orbit calculation.

Comment: So you have ruled out mis-application. Is that the only application?

Comment: Well, you could use it to compare to an orbit without additional forces, maybe even calculate the force from the acceleration, since you know the deviation from a frictionless orbit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the confusion comes from. Vis-viva is derived from a total energy $\epsilon$ that knows only kinetic and potential contribution (see the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation#Derivation_for_elliptic_orbits_(0_%E2%89%A4_eccentricity_%3C_1)))

$$ \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{GM}{r^2} .$$

Once the corresponding [Euler-Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) equation is computed and transformed into the co-orbiting system, it is clear that those two energies correspond to centrifugal and gravitational force. No other force. 
If you'd try to apply any other force to the system, then vis-viva is not applicable to calculate $r$ or $v$. In other words vis-viva is wrong in that case.
You would either have to know a potential for the new force you're applying, in order to derive equations of motion, or if you already know the equqtions of motion then solve them and re-derive a modified vis-viva. This however might not be possible if your force is dissipative.

Comment: There is no confusion. The definition of the Karman line is an artificially contrived scenario where a craft experiencing both lift and drag is nonetheless traveling at "orbital velocity" but not *in orbit*, because it also uses propulsion. It's an awkward, artificial definition, but to reconstruct it you need an expression for "orbital velocity" and that's where vis-viva is used. OP needs to understand that anyone can come up with their own definition. It was "space lawyers" who took this idea and ran with it.